# Prove that these lines are perpendicular

Tags: geometry, vectors

Inside the parallelogram $ABCD$ there is such a point $P$, that $PC$ = $BC$. Prove that line $BP$ is perpendicular to straight line connecting the midpoints of $ AP$ and $CD$. [image]

Please help. :(

Comment: This is from an on-going Polish math competition. Therefore I delete it for the duration of the contest. The WWW-link pointing at omj.edu.pl/uploads/attachments/1etap17.pdf didn't work in my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$, $N$ and $K$ be  midpoints of $AP$, $DC$ and $PB$ respectively.

Thus, $$\vec{MN}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{AD}+\vec{PC}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{BC}+\vec{PC}\right)=\vec{KC}$$
and since $PB\perp KC$ and $MN||KC$, we are done!

A bit of explanation:
$$\vec{MN}=\vec{MA}+\vec{AD}+\vec{DN}$$ and
$$\vec{MN}=\vec{MD}+\vec{DC}+\vec{CN}.$$

Thus, $$\vec{MN}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{MA}+\vec{AD}+\vec{DN}+\vec{MD}+\vec{DC}+\vec{CN}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{MA}+\vec{MD}+\vec{DN}+\vec{CN}+\vec{AD}+\vec{DC}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{0}+\vec{0}+\vec{AD}+\vec{DC}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{AD}+\vec{DC}\right).$$

Let $PCBE$ be parallelogram.

Thus, $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{PC}+\vec{BC}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{PC}+\vec{EP}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\vec{EC}=\vec{KC}.$$

There is another way!

Easy to see that $MNCK$ is parallelogram ($MK=NC$ and $MK||NC$) and we are done!

Comment: Unbelievable! :D thank you

Comment: @Caroline.math You are welcome!

Comment: I don't clearly see why 0,5(BC+PC)=KC

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: How can I do it?